# Put specified index from an array in the top of select box

Tags: php, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
   [2] => Afganistan
   [3] => Africa
   [4] => Albania
   [5] => Alegira
   [6] => Turcia
 )
```

In the template .handlebars I do :

```
{{#each oForm.lCountry}}
    <option value="{{@key}}">
      {{this}}
    </option>
{{/each}}
```

In the first value of selectbox I get `Afganistan`, how to do a verification tu put on the first value `Turcia` ?
Please help me. Thx in advance and sorry for my english

Comment: Just reorder your php array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just mark "Turcia" as selected.

**Handlebars Helper:** (Javascript version)

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eq', function(a, b, block) {
    return a == b ? block.fn(this) : block.inverse(this);
});
```

**Template:**

```
{{#each oForm.lCountry}}
    <option value="{{@key}}" {{#eq this 'Turcia'}}selected="true"{{/eq}}>
      {{this}}
    </option>
{{/each}}
```

**Output:**

```
<option value="2" >
    Afganistan
</option>
...
<option value="6" selected="true">
    Turcia
</option>
```

Now "Turcia", will be selected by default. Which is more logical so you can mantain the alphabetical order.

If you want "Turcia" to appear first by any means, just change the order of the array in PHP.